# what does bash-4.4$ refers to?

Tags: linux, bash, server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7IAH.png)I've bought a server in Hostinger and loaded my project. After that I've connected the server with ssh to my vs code and working on my project while I am handling terminal I can see the prompt something call bash-4.4$(some linux like) with that I cant use sudo, root, apt, etc,. most of the linux commands I can't use. May be the hostinger restricts the user to do that but how can i install the required tools like apache, etc

Can Someone Help me ?

Comment: [restricted bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289471/whats-the-usage-of-rbash) is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: The shell prompt is configurable at runtime.  You're describing the default prompt (for Bash version 4.4).  Perhaps you've never seen the default prompt before, as it's common for Linux distributions to provide customized shell prompt configuration to all users.

Comment: In any case, this is a matter to take up with your provider.  There are very good reasons why they might limit what you can do, but they might also have a procedure for obtaining more privileges, or else an alternative way to achieve the results you want.

Comment: I second what @JohnBollinger said. You should consult the Hostinger documentation for the server type you purchased, or else contact Hostinger support for help. Perhaps there is a way to gain root access on the server to install whatever software packages you desire, perhaps you need to purchase a different server type in order to have that kind of access, or perhaps you can purchase a server with the required software preinstalled.

Comment: Thank you for all al your brief explanation, now I've got an idea for further move.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash-4.4$` is a shell prompt, [you can read more about it here.](https://www.quora.com/What-does-%E2%80%98bash-4-4-%E2%80%99-mean)

You can install new software on the machine only if you have `root` access or your current user have `sudo` access (sudoers file)

You can type:

`$ whoami`

To see your current user.

And

`$ cat /etc/*-release`

To see all the information about your current linux distro.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the goal of me is to use apache there is no apache in that to install I shld give the cmd sudo apt install apache - here the error is thrown that sudo is not recognized

Comment: If you're getting `sudo: command not found` then you should contact the Hostinger support or documentation and understand what are the the given privileges you have on your server.